# VBA results in #VALUE! only when For loop is used

Tags: excel, vba, function, for-loop

I am writing a function with a For loop, and ultimately the value of the function will depend on the output of the For loop. For now as a test, the value of the function is a constant. If the For loop is in the code, the function results in #Value!. If I remove the For loop, the output is the specified constant value. How does the For loop need to be specified to avoid this? Good values for Tc and Th as a test would be 100 and 300, respectively.

```
Function kndT(material As Integer, Tc As Double, Th As Double) As Variant
Dim x As Double
Select Case material
    Case 4
        If Th > 300 Then
            Tmax = 300
        Else
            Tmax = Th
        End If
        A = 0.07918
        b = 1.0957
        c = -0.07277
        D = 0.08084
        e = 0.02803
        f = -0.09464
        g = 0.04179
        h = -0.00571
        i = 0
End Select
hh = (Tmax - Tc) / 999
fi = 0
nc = 1
For i = 1 To 999
    Temp = (Tc + i * hh)
    x = Log(Temp) / Log(10#)
    y = A + b * x + c * x ^ 2 + D * x ^ 3 + e * x ^ 4 + f * x ^ 5 + g * x ^ 6 + h * x ^ 7 + i * x ^ 8
    fn = 10 ^ y
    If nc = 3 Then
        fi = fi + 2 * fn
        nc = 1
    Else
        fi = fi + 3 * fn
        nc = nc + 1
    End If
Next i
kndT = 2
End Function
```

Comment: `fn = 10 ^ y` gives an `Overflow` error.

Comment: You've used `i` as both an index and a coefficient

Comment: I tried it with just using `i` as 1 and as 999, it worked fine, then in the loop I was getting an OVERFLOW error - It's probably down to repeatedly adding to `fi` using `fi = fi + 2 * fn`

Comment: `fi` isn't reset on your looping, it's just added to for each iteration using `fn` as a multiplier, and with `fn` raised to `y` then I imagine it's getting ridiculous after 999 iterations.

Comment: @JMP that did the trick. Thanks. Thats what was causing the OVERFLOW.